# CSS Transform and Pseudo classes

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

Using :after, I'm trying to create brutalist pseudo 3D button.
But the :after is showing above the intended element.

[What I'm Trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxUdJ.png)

[What I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8GXu.png)

Edit: Obviously the transform is getting in the way, research has yet to yield a why or find a work around.

What am I missing? Or is there a better way?

```css
nav li {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  transition: background 0.2s;
  transform: skewX(10deg);
}
nav li a {
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font: 30px/1 sans-serif;
  color: #0bf;
}
nav li.active,
nav li:hover{
  background:#000;
}

nav li.active:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Products</a>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: it sounds interesting but you may need to refine your question, to avoid downvotes and close flags.

Comment: The syntax to indicate a pseudo-element is the double-colon - `::`. The pseudo-elements are `::before` and `::after`.

Comment: @Rounin While that is true, browsers are officially required to support the single colon syntax too. According to the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/), "user agents must also accept the previous one-colon notation (`:before` and `:after`) for these pseudo-elements."

Comment: I don't doubt it. But there is (arguable) utility in distingushing `pseudo-elements` from `pseudo-classes` in stylesheets.

Comment: @Rounin I agree. But just on a pragmatic level, if the question says "my `:after` isn't working", you'll know that changing `:after` to `::after` will not do anything to solve the problem.

Comment: I agree 100%. But it was a comment, not a solution. I wrote my solution below. Then I saw your solution and realised that they were almost identical. Then I deleted my solution and upvoted yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voila... Just edited this part:

```
nav li.active,
nav li:hover{
  background:#000;
}
```

... which should be:

```
nav li.active a,
nav li:hover a{
  background:#000;
}
```

Here is the working code:

```css
nav li {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  transition: background 0.2s;
  transform: skewX(10deg);
}
nav li a {
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font: 30px/1 sans-serif;
  color: #0bf;
}
nav li.active a,
nav li:hover a{
  background:#000;
}

nav li.active:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Products</a>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Perfect! It's always the little things. Thanks a lot! @JoostS

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an `:after`, you can use a `box-shadow`.

```css
nav li {
  position: relative; z-index:0;
  display:inline-block;
  transition: background 0.2s;
  transform: skewX(10deg);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0 red;
}
nav li a {
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font: 30px/1 sans-serif;
  color: #0bf;
}
nav li.active,
nav li:hover{
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    
    <li class="active">
      <a href="#">Products</a>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
</nav>
```